# Can't convert from hexadecimal from a file to decimal form using a switch

Tags: java, file, hex, decimal

I have been trying to work on a project for hours now and I can't seem to figure out how to convert a file of hexadecimals into decimals using a switch. It keeps coming back with numbers like this: 
This program converts hexadecimal numbers into decimal numbers. 
The hexadecimal 2102 is: -2   all the way to this:
The hexadecimal 124F is: 9342467183 
Here is the code I've got so far:

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class hexToDecimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        java.io.File in_file = new java.io.File("hex_data.txt");
        Scanner fnput = new Scanner(in_file);
        String[] hexL = new String[25] ;
        int[] dec = new int [25] ;
        long decNum = 0 ;
        System.out.printf("This program converts hexadecimal numbers into decimal numbers. \n");


        for(int a = 0 ; a < 25 ; a++) {
            String hex = fnput.nextLine();
            hexL[a] = hex.substring(2).toUpperCase() ;
            hexL[a] = hexL[a].trim();

            int powerNum = hexL.length - a - 1;
            dec[a] = hexL[a].charAt(dec[a]);
            //dec[a] = pow(16, a) ; 
        switch(dec[a]){
        case '0':decNum = 0 * pow(16, powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case '1':decNum = 1 * pow(16,powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case '2':decNum = 2 * pow(16,powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case '3':decNum = 3 * pow(16,powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case '4':decNum = 4 * pow(16,powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case '5':decNum = 5 * pow(16,powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case '6':decNum = 6 * pow(16,powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case '7':decNum = 7 * pow(16,powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case '8':decNum = 8 * pow(16,powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case '9':decNum = 9 * pow(16,powerNum) + decNum;break;
        case 'A':decNum = 10 * pow(16,powerNum)+ decNum;break;
        case 'B':decNum = 11 * pow(16,powerNum)+ decNum;break;
        case 'C':decNum = 12 * pow(16,powerNum)+ decNum;break;
        case 'D':decNum = 13 * pow(16,powerNum)+ decNum;break;
        case 'E':decNum = 14 * pow(16,powerNum)+ decNum;break;
        case 'F':decNum = 15 * pow(16,powerNum)+ decNum;break;

        }   


        System.out.println("The hexadecimal " + hexL[a] + " is: " + decNum);
        }

    } // end of function main()


    public static int pow(int i, int powerNum) {

         return (int) Math.pow( 16, powerNum);  


            }// end of function convertHex()    

} // end of class hexToDecimal
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to put this in a debugger and watch it run step by step.

The number you use to accumulate your answer is not getting cleared for each of the 25 different strings you decode.

You are also using the same variable for too many things. The statement

```
dec[a] = hexL[a].charAt(dec[a]);
```

is an interesting convolution; dec[a] is used as an index into the string at hexL[a], and the resulting character is then assigned to dec[a]? So that value will be the integer equivalent of the character; I don't know that that's useful for anything, and have a hard time believing you meant what this does.

After you figure out what this code is doing, try writing pseudo-code comments on what you are trying to do.

```
// read the next string from the file

// for each character in this string,
//   get the decimal equivalent of this hexadecimal character
//   multiply the decimal equivalent and the power of 16 represented by 
//      this character's position in the string.
//   add the result to the resulting decimal conversion for this string of hex
```

Then go back and put in a statement or two per comment that does what you have in the comment. I think it may help you plan out what your code is doing, and will certainly help anyone trying to read the code understand what you were trying to do when you wrote it.